# Why should I use `.Include(...)` to include navigation properties?

Tags: entity-framework

Why should I put `.Include(...)` while the view has visibility on all navigation properties?

1. action1

   ```
    public ActionResult Included(){
        var models = db.Money.Include(m=>m.Rate);
        return View(models);
    }
   ```
2. action2

   ```
    public ActionResult UnIncluded(){
        var models = db.Money;
        return View(models);
    }
   ```

In both views I may get the amount as follows

```
   @Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Rate.Amount)
```

So, what is the difference? 
Is this what we know as lazy load mode?

Comment: When using an include, the foreign object is loaded using a join, without include each foreign object is loaded using a separate query... (assuming lazy loading is enabled)

Comment: @Rico Suter: I am not sure you are right, from my experience omitting "include" makes all collections return "null" - going against "wihtout include each foreign object is loaded using a separate query".

Comment: What do you mean by "while the view has visibility on all navigation properties"?

Comment: You should read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: @Bellash: by the way, you seem to suggest that "in both views I get the ammount as follows" - the result is the same with and without include - what's "Rate" data type ? Is a collection ?

Comment: @Veverke if you are getting `null` values when you don't use `.Include`, make sure your navigation properties are `virtual`. When navigation properties are `virtual` and lazy loading is enabled, they should not come back null, but should instead be loaded in a separate SQL query operation.

Comment: @danludwig: I remember they were virtual, the case may have been that lazy loading was off (although... I think I also turned it on and it kept not working. The only thing that fixed the problem was adding Include).

Comment: Thank you all! your comments where appreciated!
Lazy loading was the tip I feel lazy to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, what is the difference? Is this what we know as lazy load mode?

Yes.

Assume your `Money` table has 1000 rows. Also assuming that `Rate` is a navigation property, the following will execute 1001 separate SQL queries:

```
public ActionResult UnIncluded(){
     var models = db.Money;
     return View(models);
}
...
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Rate.Amount)
```

Why? The above action will return only the `Money` data to the view. Then the view, while iterating over each `Money` instance, will lazily load each and every `.Rate` instance. This means 1000 extra SQL queries, one for each `Money` item in the collection.

However, the following will only execute 1 SQL query:

```
public ActionResult Included(){
     var models = db.Money.Include(m=>m.Rate);
     return View(models);
 }
...
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Rate.Amount)
```

Why? The above action will execute a single SQL query that performs a JOIN between the `Money` and `Rate` tables to load all of the `Rate` data for each of the 1000 `Money` rows *in only one round trip to the database*. This is known as eager-loading.

[As @IronMan84 says,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27800994/304832) this is assuming that you have lazy loading enabled, and that `Rate` is a `virtual` navigation property on `Money`.

Answer (score 3):

`.Include` forces the specified property to be loaded eagerly, as opposed to lazily, assuming that lazy loading is turned on in your application. So in your first action `Rate` will have been brought back from the database right away, as opposed to your second action in which it will only be brought over (again, assuming lazy loading is on) when it's called for (i.e. when you call for `model.Rate.Amount` on the page).

One thing that you should be aware of: If you're using lazy loading, it would actually behoove you to use `.Include` or to use `.ToList()` in your controller action, because you could possibly run into situations in which you get an exception because your controller has disposed the `DbContext` object *before* the View calls for a navigational property that requires EF to go back to the database. So `Action1` above might be the better way to go just to avoid that situation.

MSDN post on `Include` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you man, 
Lazy loading is the only tip I'm lazy to learn! Now I feel it important!